# How to use @Html.DropDownList by giving values manually?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to use `@Html.DropDownList` without any model but simply as we use **select** in normal html.

Please revert, Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use normal html?

Comment: Because I want to bind value coming from the controller as its default value. @DaveBecker

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, u may understand we the following example.

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedState", new List<SelectListItem>
                                {
                                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Not verified", Value = "1"},
                                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Verified", Value = "2"},
                                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Migrated", Value = "3"}
                                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Completed", Value = "4"}
                                }, "All states", new { @onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Html.Dropdownlist without model
for example in controller you set the values for Dropdownlist,

```
var dates = new List<SelectListItem>{
new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for all dates", Value = ""},
new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for today", Value = today.ToShortDateString()},
new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for this week", Value = endOfThisWeek.ToShortDateString()},
new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for this month", Value = endOfThisMonth.ToShortDateString()},
new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Show offers for further out", Value = all.ToShortDateString()},};
ViewBag.Dropdowndata = dates;
```

and you can access the values of Viewbag from View and set it to Dropdown list like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <label>
                Select Dates</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("Dates", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dropdowndata, "---Select---", new { id = "dateList" ,@class = "form-control" });
        }
```